# Where does the Newtonian proof of angular momentum conservation assume rotational invariance?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, angular-momentum, symmetry, noethers-theorem

Suppose there is a particle whose position, velocity and acceleration are $\vec{r(t)}$, $\vec{v(t) }$, $\vec{a(t) }$.
$\vec{a(t) }$ is always directed along $\vec{r(t) }$ but $|a|$ is not just a function of $|r|$, but explicitly depends on the co-ordinates.

This system is not rotationally invariant, but the Newtonian proof of angular momentum conservation still holds because $\vec{a(t) }$ is aligned with $\vec{r(t) }$:

$$\frac{d(\vec{r}\times \vec{v}) }{dt}=\vec{v}\times \vec{v}+\vec{r}\times \vec{a}=0$$

Then, is the Newtonian proof more general than the Lagrangian proof? The Newtonian angular momentum is conserved even without rotational symmetry.

Comment: I think the problem is in you definition of a *system*.  You are talking about only one particular trajectory the particle can take, but what if the particle starts at some *other* point with some *other* velocity. It will probably *not* follow a trajectory for which $\vec{a}$ is parallel to $\vec{v}$, and hence angular momentum might not be conserved. The issue is that you seem to be mixing up one trajectory with the system. The point is, it's certainly possible for the angular momentum to be conserved along *one particular* trajectory, even when the system isn't rotationally invariant...

Comment: ...but it won't be conserved along *every* possible trajectory that might be followed by a particle in that system (e.g., feeling that particular force field).  One possible resolution is to note that symmetry guarantees conservation along *every* trajectory, but this is not an if and only if. In other words, *not*-symmetric guarantees at least one trajectory having non-conservation.  I don't think this makes Newtonian physics more general than that based on Lagrangians, because this stuff is in there, too.

Comment: @march why write answer as a comment? This is not useful for anyone but OP.

Comment: @Umaxo. With questions like this, I usually don't like to write an answer until I'm sure of what the OP is getting at. I *think* I've addressed their question, but I'm not sure, so my comments were really aimed at eliciting a (brief) discussion in the comments to see if the OP basically agreed with my interpretation and answer. But I see that you've written an answer similar to my comments, so now I don't have to write an answer!

Comment: @march You can consider a fictional 2D universe of one particle, where the force law, with respect to some fixed origin, is $\vec{F}= m (x+2y) \vec{r}$. Clearly, this is not a rotationally symmetric force law, but the force, by design, is always parallel to $\vec{r}$, regardless of the specific path. Hence, the conservation of $\vec {r}\times m\vec{v}$ is valid even without rotational invariance. This is what I addressed in my answer.

Comment: @march I'm not sure but maybe it is possible to derive this fictional force law from a fictional principle of least action. In that case, the conservation law would still be there, because we would be formulating the same physical theory. But I suppose the conservation of $\vec{r}\times \vec{v}$ would be a consequence of some **other** symmetry of the Lagrangian than a rotational symmetry, cuz the Lagrangian obviously can't be rotationally symmetric

Comment: @RyderRude a 2D universe doesn't have angular momentum defined through a cross product as the cross product only lives in 3D and certain higher dimensions. Also it doesn't have the proper dimensions of a force.

Comment: @Triatticus You can add a dimensional constant to get the dimensions right. It's no different from how there's a $G$ in the Gravitational law. Also, an equivalent of the cross product can be defined using the determinant. The Newtonian proof of the conservation law holds in this universe.

Comment: @RyderRude it's just that any other object in the plane doesn't see orbital motion, any motion with an orbit appears like linear harmonic motion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I could have made the exact same argument for momentum conservation too. I could just say that all the forces on a system are equal and opposite, but the forces explicitly depend on the co-ordinates, instead of the separation $(x_1-x_2) $. Then the system wouldn't be translationally invariant and momentum would still be conserved.

This means that Newtonian proofs are indeed more general. These proofs do not require symmetries for conservation.

The additional assumption that goes into the Lagrangian proofs is that the forces are derive-able by a potential term. So the Lagrangian mechanics is tighter than Newton's three laws.

Comment: Lagrangian mechanics is indeed tighter then Newtonian, but not for this reason. If you have system for which Lagrangian mechanics is applicable, it is equivalent to Newtonian. The proofs you provided can be also made in Lagrangian mechanics. But Newtonian mechanics is applicable in areas where Lagrangian mechanics is not - most notably for systems with frictional forces.

Comment: @Umaxo You can consider a fictional 2D universe of one particle, where the force law, with respect to some fixed origin, is $\vec{F}= m (x+2y) \vec{r}$. Clearly, this is not a rotationally symmetric force law, but the force, by design, is always parallel to $\vec{r}$,  regardless of the specific path. Hence, the conservation of $\vec {r}\times m\vec{v}$ is valid even without rotational invariance. This is what I addressed in my answer.

Comment: @Umaxo I'm not sure but maybe it is possible to derive this fictional force law from a fictional principle of least action. In that case, the conservation law would still be there, because we would be formulating the same physical theory. But I suppose the conservation of $\vec{r}\times \vec{v}$ would be a consequence of some **other** symmetry of the Lagrangian than a rotational symmetry,  cuz the Lagrangian obviously can't be rotationally symmetric

Comment: @RydeRude Indeed. Also, as far as I know, Noether theorem states that each differentiable symmetry leads to conserved current, not that each conserved quantity leads to a symmetry.